# rerender page after ExternalContext.redirect in actionListener Method

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

I have a a4j:commandButton whose actionListener method calls ExternalContext.redirect. In the a4j:commandButton, I have specified a reRender, but it seems as if calling ExternalContext.redirect causes the reRender to not happen. Is there anyway that I can have the reRender to work?

```
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true" > 
        <rich:panel id="lastPrint">
          <label>Last Printed By</label>
          <h:outputText value="#{report.lastPrintPerson.name.displayName}"/>
          <label>Last Printed On</label>
          <h:outputText value="#{report.printedOnDate}" />
        </rich:panel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>

<a4j:commandButton style="buttonLeft" value="Print"  actionListener="#{reportHandler.printReport}"
        reRender="lastPrint" ajaxSingle="true">

 public void printReport()
{
        String reportUrl = "http://someurl";
        report.setLastPrintPersonId(User.instance().getPerson().getId());
        report.setPrintedOnDate(new Date());
        reportManager.updateReport(report);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(reportUrl);
}
```

Comment: Try change signature of printReport to `public String printReport`, add return null as last line of printReport method, use `action` attribute in commandButton like <a4j:commandButton style="buttonLeft" value="Print"  action="#{yourBean.printReport}" 
reRender="lastPrint" />`

Comment: @VasilLukach I've tried that. Same results.

Comment: I have exact same construction with getExternalContext().redirect() and it works fine with `action` attribute. In my case URL is internal in application and it called like this: `getFacesContext().getExternalContext().redirect(getRequest().getContextPath() + "/pageName.jsf?" + Constants.SOME_PARAM + "="+someBean.getSomeCode())`

Comment: That is probably the difference. The URL that I redirect to is in another application. Thanks for the suggestion.